# Align vertices along a face(not in x, y, z axis)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i had a face(pic 1) and after add solidify modifier, there were some weird shading issue(pic 2), and i cannot fix it. i thought may be the reason that some of these vertice were not on the same face. so i try to align them along a face. After search it on google, still cannot figure it out.
Can any one help me out?
Or maybe point out the reason of the shading issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file so that we understand what happens, perhaps you need to recalculate the normals?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for replying, i solved the problem already, something wrong with the normal. Thank you!